# RStudio: can I pop out the source pane?

Tags: rstudio

I have a dual monitor and I wish I can pop out the "source pane"(where I edit my code), so that I can edit the code in one monitor and track everything else in another.

Does anyone know if this is possible?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 42):

This feature was just added to RStudio this week. You can try it in our daily builds (0.99.636 or newer):

https://dailies.rstudio.com/

To pop out your file to a new window, either:

1. Drag the tab outside the RStudio window to where you want your new code window to appear, or
2. Click the "Show in new window" button on the editor toolbar (it's next to forward/back)

If you try it, let us know what you think on the [support forum](http://support.rstudio.com).

Comment: Hi Jonathan, overall I really like this new feature. It definitely makes me more productive.

It would be even better if there is a simple way to put the the code window back to where it is. Say I can drag it back or I can double click the title bar to make it pop out and come back.

Thanks for spending time and addressing my question. I appreciate the support RStudio team offers to its users.

Comment: Great, glad it's working for you! You can drag individual tabs back into the main window--does that do what you want? If not a good place to file a request is here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/topics/200022758-Feature-Requests

Comment: How have I lived without knowing this for the last 3 years, don't know.

Comment: is it possible to detach the console and the memstack?

Comment: separate editor windows, btw, have a bug when the scrollbar autosnaps to mouse cursor

Answer (score 6):

I'm using the latest Studio and encountered similar needs. I found that ctrl+shift+number will suit my needs most of the time since it zooms to the pane that I desire and can also back to the full four window layout.

An additional trick is customize the hotkey to alt+number [1,2,3,4,5] so the pane zooms more handy with one click by your left hand on the keyboard.

Hope it helps.