# How to only display code File pane on top (all width), Console and File/Plot panes below

Tags: rstudio

I would like to know how do I leave the code part on top and the console and File/Plot panels dividing the bottom part?

I would like to remove the Enviroment / History panel and let only this  3 panels.

Many thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, from https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200549016-Customizing-RStudio: *"Each of the 4 panes is always displayed (it isn't currently possible to hide a pane)."*

Comment: @r2evans You can *minimise* panes, but that only stretches panes vertically, not horizontally. That said, I question the usefulness of a horizontally stretched code panel: height i much more important than width for code.

Comment: yes. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2854

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31280054/3358272

Answer (score 2):

While I don't think you can do it in one window, as suggested by @jjallaire (https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2854#issuecomment-426271459):

> One way to approximate this right now is to pop out a separate source pane and position it next to the main IDE.

To do this,

1. Grab the code tab outside of the window: for me, it seems like it doesn't want me to do this based on the red circle-slash, but just drag it outside the RStudio window and you'll get a new window with just that source file
2. Maximize your code and plot windows
3. Use your window manager (or just manual window-resizing) to fill the space

[image: sample layout]

Different window managers might offer the ability to "snap" these windows into place. On Windows, for example, if you install PowerToys/FancyZones (https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/tree/master/src/modules/fancyzones), you can define a custom layout (two zones, each wide and half-height) and snap then into place.

(I recognize that this is imperfect, but it appears to be the only way to get wide-code.)